# React is setstate messing up my algorithm?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react, and have implemented a simple visual selection sort. I run the selection sort whenever the button is clicked. From my understanding, the whole algorithm should run and the data be sorted from one click. However, it takes multiple button clicks to sort the entire data. I am assuming this is due to react updating the state and rendering new components in my function call for selection sort.

Any help is much appreciated !

```
class Square extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: null,
            heightSet: 3,
            sorted: false,
        };
    }
  render() {
    var myheight = this.props.heightSet + 'em';
    var sort = this.props.sorted;
    var bgcolor = 'grey';
    var key = this.props.value;
      if (sort){
          bgcolor = 'green';
      }
      else{
          bgcolor = 'grey';
      }
    var divHeightStyle = {
    height: myheight,
    backgroundColor: bgcolor,
    };
    return (
      <div
        id={this.props.value}
        value={this.props.heightSet}
        style={divHeightStyle}
        className="square">
        {this.props.value}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Rectangle extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    };





    render(){
        return (
            <button
                className="rectangle"
                onClick={() => this.props.selectionSort()} >
            </button>
        )

    }
}

class Board extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            squares: [],
            sorted: [],
        };
        const min = 1;
        const max = 80;
        const rand1 = min + Math.random() * (max - min)
        const rand2 = min + Math.random() * (max - min)
        const rand3 = min + Math.random() * (max - min)
        const maxbars = 50;
        for(let i=0; i<maxbars; i++){
            let rand = min + Math.random() * (max - min)
            this.state.squares[i] = rand;
            this.state.sorted[i] = false;
        }

    }
  renderSquare(i, y, z) {
    return <Square value={i} heightSet={y} sorted={z}/>;
  }


    selectionSort(){
        let i, j, min_idx;
        let finished = 0;
        for(let i=0; i<11; i++)
        {
            min_idx = i;
            for(let j=i+1; j < 12; j++)
            {
                if(this.state.squares[j] < this.state.squares[min_idx])
                {
                    min_idx = j;
                    let temp = this.state.squares[min_idx];
                    this.state.squares[min_idx] = this.state.squares[i];
                    this.state.squares[i] = temp;

                    this.state.sorted[finished] = true;
                    finished++;
                    this.setState({ squares: this.state.squares
                                  })
                    this.setState({ sorted: this.state.sorted

                    })
                }
            }

        }

    }

    renderRectangle() {
        return <Rectangle
        selectionSort={this.selectionSort.bind(this)}
        />;
    }

    render() {
    const status = '';

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="rec-wrapper">
        {this.renderRectangle()}
        </div>
        <div className="status">{status}</div>
        <div className="board-row">
          <div className="square-wrapper">
          {this.renderSquare(1,this.state.squares[0],this.state.sorted[0])}
          {this.renderSquare(2,this.state.squares[1],this.state.sorted[1])}
          {this.renderSquare(3,this.state.squares[2],this.state.sorted[2])}
          {this.renderSquare(4,this.state.squares[3],this.state.sorted[3])}
          {this.renderSquare(5,this.state.squares[4],this.state.sorted[4])}
          {this.renderSquare(6,this.state.squares[5],this.state.sorted[5])}
          {this.renderSquare(7,this.state.squares[6],this.state.sorted[6])}
          {this.renderSquare(8,this.state.squares[7],this.state.sorted[7])}
          {this.renderSquare(9,this.state.squares[8],this.state.sorted[8])}
          {this.renderSquare(10,this.state.squares[9],this.state.sorted[9])}
          {this.renderSquare(11,this.state.squares[10],this.state.sorted[10])}
          {this.renderSquare(12,this.state.squares[11],this.state.sorted[11])}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're mutating state directly, which you shouldn't do.

```
this.state.squares[i] = rand;
this.state.sorted[i] = false;
```

should be

```
const squares = [...this.state.squares];
squares[i] = rand;

const sorted = [...this.state.sorted];
sorted[i] = false;

this.setState({
  squares: squares,
  sorted: sorted  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

React's `setState` [runs async](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#when-is-setstate-asynchronous), therefore setting it in a loop will give you unexpected results.

You will want to just call `setState` once after your loop is done running.

```
selectionSort(){
    let i, j, min_idx;
    let finished = 0;
    let squareResult = [...this.state.squares];
    let stortedResult = [...this.state.sorted]

    for(let i=0; i<11; i++)
    {
        min_idx = i;
        for(let j=i+1; j < 12; j++)
        {
            if(squareResult[j] < squareResult[min_idx])
            {
                min_idx = j;
                let temp = squareResult[min_idx];
                squareResult[min_idx] = squareResult[i];
                squareResult[i] = temp;

                sortedResult[finished] = true;
                finished++;                
            }
        }
        this.setState({ squares: squareResult, sorted: sortedResult })                
    }

}
```

Comment: Since `this.state.squares` and `this.state.sorted` are arrays, this is still technically mutating the array, since arrays are stored by reference in JS. Creating a new reference to them in a variable, i.e. through `let squareResult = this.state.squares;` doesn't create a copy of the array, it creates a _reference_ to that same array. So when mutating `squareResult` you're actually mutating the state array. This approach may still technically work, but still involves state mutation, which should never be done.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what james has purposed. Maybe an improvement could be made on the setState method by changing it to

```js
this.setState({ squares: [...squareResult], sorted:[...sortedResult]})
```